# Wrapping text in a cell without exapanding height of the cell in libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

In libreOffice when I write in a cell, I need if the size of the text gets more than its size, the end of the text doesn't disappear and cell's height gets expanded. From the path: `Format > Cells.. > Alignment` I select 'Wrap text automatically' but when I write more than the size, it's not showed compeletely again and will be remain like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Hi H., did you notice the edited answer? Please mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that in order to solve this problem I can double click on the line of borders which the related cell gets expanded

Answer (score 2):

By default, the cell expands, like you mention.

#### Unless...

You force the cell to a certain hight by clicking on the row on the left, choose <kbd>Row hight</kbd> (<kbd>Rijhoogte</kbd> in Dutch):

[image]

#### Example:

***This***

[image]

becomes:

[image]

#### How to save the time to set all rows individually

Although I couldn't find any setting to change the default behaviour for cells/rows, you can easily work around:

- In a new document, before changing cells etc, click in the top/left blank square, where rows/columns cross each other, to select all cells/rows.
- Right- click on the left of first row, Choose <kbd>Row hight</kbd>, simply press return.
- Again, while all cells/rows are selected, right- click on the left of first row, choose Format > Cells.. > Alignment, set to wrap.

Now the document will behave like you want, for all cells in all rows.

Comment: I don't want to change the row height for each row separately! Is there any way that it automatically get expanded?

Comment: @M.Hossein, select all the cells by clicking the box to the upper left between column A and row 1.  Then adjust row height and column width with a right click on any one of the columns and any one of the rows and it will apply to the whole sheet.